# Calling one procedure from another procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

The code below is saved in a file named proc1.sql

```
DECLARE
    B VARCHAR2(25);
    C NUMBER;

PROCEDURE Get_manager_detailS(NO IN NUMBER,NAME OUT VARCHAR2,SAL1 OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT ENAME, SAL 
    INTO NAME, SAL1 
    FROM EMP 
    WHERE EMPNO = NO;
END;
BEGIN
Get_manager_detailS(7900,B,C);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(B);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C);
END;
/
```

This procedure is stored in another file proc3.sql

```
PROCEDURE Test_Procedure()
IS
BEGIN
b varchar2(25);
c number;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALLING');
 Get_manager_details(7900,b,c);
END;
```

When I am running it in sqlplus, it is showing an error

> SP2-0734 UNKNOWN COMMAND BEGINING PROCEDURE.. REST OF THE LINES IGNORED.
>   SP2-0042 UNKNOWN COMMAND" IS "..REST OF THE LINE IGNORED.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a PROCEDURE/FUNCTION vs. ANONYMOUS BLOCK

- > Stored PROCEDURES/FUNCTIONS always starts with **CREATE OR REPLACE ...** and ends with END;
  >
  > CREATE OR REPLACE serves as the implicit declare for stored functions and procedures, thus you dont have to write DECLARE anymore inside the block
- > An anonymous block starts with **DECLARE** and ends with **END;**

As for the code/block of codes saved in proc1.sql.

- Your declaration is misplaced.You should place it after the end of
  the procedure
- Start the procedure with CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE

Try This Block:

```
    -- DECLARE              
    -- B VARCHAR2(25);
    -- C NUMBER;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_manager_detailS(NO IN NUMBER,
                                                     NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
                                                     SAL1 OUT NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT ENAME, SAL 
        INTO NAME, SAL1 
        FROM EMP 
            WHERE EMPNO = NO;
    END; -- end of procedure

    /

    DECLARE --  start of anonymous block              
      B VARCHAR2(25);
      C NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      Get_manager_detailS(7900,B,C);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(B);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C);
    END;
```

As for the procedure that will call the get_manager_details procedure.Its will be just the same as the anonymous block, the only difference will be is that it is stored

Base from what have you done already

- > If you will not declare parameters in your procedure, parenthesis are not necessary so remove it.
- > If you dont have output parameters that will catch the result of your procedure, you can use dbms_output.put_line as you have used in 
  >   the anonymous block above
- > variable declarations should be done after the IS keyword and before BEGIN statements, because as I have noted above **CREATE OR
  >   REPLACE ... IS** is the implicit declare for the stored functions and
  >   procedures

TRY THIS:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_Procedure
    IS -- always start with CREATE OR REPLACE
      b varchar2(25);
      c number;

    BEGIN
  --  b varchar2(25); misplaced declarations
  --  c number;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALLING');
       Get_manager_details(7900,b,c);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(B); -- displays the results b
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C); -- and c

    END;
```

Sorry for the long post.

HOPE THIS HELPS.

CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

Your first block is anonymous block in which you declare procedure - you can call procedure `Get_manager_details` within anonymous block only. You can't call `Get_manager_details` from `Test_Procedure` because there is no such procedure. You need to create your procedure `Get_manager_details` first

```
Create or replace procedure Get_manager_details ....
```

Then you can run

```
Create or replace procedure Test_Procedure ....
```

Or it will not compile.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to call the procedure get_manager_details inside test_procedure then you first need to create the test procedure.
Add create or replace procedure test_procedure .
Then after creating the test_procedure you can execute it  in an anonymous block which will call the get_manager_details procedure.